# $\left | \frac{x^{2}-2}{x} \right| \cdot\left | \frac{x}{x^{2}-2} \right|\neq 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I'm sorry if I ask something trivial and about basic math.
Why I cannot simplify two absolute values?

I'm considering

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left [ \log\left | \frac{x^{2}-2}{x} \right|  \right ]=\left | \frac{x^{2}-2}{x} \right| \cdot\left | \frac{x}{x^{2}-2} \right|\cdot \frac{x}{x^{2}-2}\cdot\frac{2x^{2}-2-x^{2}}{x^{2}}\mapsto \frac{x^{2}+2}{x^{3}-2x}.$$

Why the following equality is true?
  $$\left | \frac{x^{2}-2}{x} \right| \cdot\left | \frac{x}{x^{2}-2} \right|\neq 1.$$

Comment: It is true, you can simplify! (Assuming the terms are defined).

Comment: The equality (meaning with =1) is true whenever $x\neq 0,\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: About what your considering: $\frac{\partial |x|}{\partial x} = \frac{|x|}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

> For all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ it is true that 
>   $$\vert a\cdot b\vert = \vert a \vert \cdot \vert b \vert \tag{1}$$

This is the [multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Real_numbers) property. As stated in the comments by Wore and Zestylemonzi you'll have that, for $x \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ we have that

$$\frac{x^2-2}{x} \in \mathbb{R}$$

and for $x \in \mathbb{R}-\{-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\}$ you'll get

$$\frac{x}{x^2-2}\in \mathbb{R}$$

so using $(1)$ you get that the equality is true if $x$ satisfies both $x \neq 0$ and $x\neq \sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$.